# how to spin and stop wheel has custom position with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

**this i my code.** 
I am using this CSS code I want to spin my wheel:

now i want to spin and stop wheel has custom position with jquery?
like lucky wheeel in https://hockey-empire.com/
i'm a newbie, please help me :)

```js
var color    = ['#FF0000','#FF0000','#FF0000','#FF0000','#FF0000','#FF0000'];//list color
 var label    = ['googluck', '10%','Thank','10$','5$','10$',"20%"]; //list lable  name 
 var slices   = color.length;
 var sliceDeg = 360/slices;
 var deg      = -90;
 var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var width  = canvas.width; // size
 var center = width/2;      // center
  var slices = color.length;
 var sliceDeg = 360 / slices;
 var deg = -90;
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var width = canvas.width;// size
 var center = width / 2; // center
 function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
 }
 function drawSlice(deg, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.moveTo(center, center);
  ctx.arc(center, center, width / 2, deg2rad(deg), deg2rad(deg + sliceDeg));
  ctx.lineTo(center, center);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
 }

 function drawPoin(deg, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.moveTo(center, center);
  ctx.arc(center, center, 50, deg2rad(deg), deg2rad(deg + sliceDeg));
  ctx.lineTo(center, center);
  ctx.fill();
 }
 function drawText(deg, text) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(center, center);
  ctx.rotate(deg2rad(deg));
  ctx.textAlign = "right";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.font = '18px Arial';
  ctx.shadowColor = "#000000";
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
  ctx.fillText(text, center - 25, 10);
  ctx.restore();
 }
 for (var i = 0; i < slices; i++) {
  drawSlice(deg, color[i]);
  drawPoin(deg, '#fff');
  drawText(deg + sliceDeg / 2, label[i]);
  deg += sliceDeg;
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD1js.jpg)
i want spin like it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using setInterval method by changing the degree in each interval, you can modify incrementer value and time setInterval to suit your speed and also break the interval using some flags or conditions

```js
window.setInterval(draw, 1);

var color    = ['#FF0000','#FF0000','#FF0000','#FF0000','#FF0000','#FF0000'];//list color
 var label    = ['googluck', '10%','Thank','10$','5$','10$',"20%"]; //list lable  name 
 var slices   = color.length;
 var sliceDeg = 360/slices;
 var deg      = -90;
 var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var width  = canvas.width; // size
 var center = width/2;      // center
  var slices = color.length;
 var sliceDeg = 360 / slices;
 var deg = -90;
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var width = canvas.width;// size
 var center = width / 2; // center
 function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
 }
 function drawSlice(deg, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.moveTo(center, center);
  ctx.arc(center, center, width / 2, deg2rad(deg), deg2rad(deg + sliceDeg));
  ctx.lineTo(center, center);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
 }

 function drawPoin(deg, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.moveTo(center, center);
  ctx.arc(center, center, 50, deg2rad(deg), deg2rad(deg + sliceDeg));
  ctx.lineTo(center, center);
  ctx.fill();
 }
 function drawText(deg, text) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(center, center);
  ctx.rotate(deg2rad(deg));
  ctx.textAlign = "right";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.font = '18px Arial';
  ctx.shadowColor = "#000000";
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
  ctx.fillText(text, center - 25, 10);
  ctx.restore();
 }
    function draw() {
        deg++;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     for (var i = 0; i < slices; i++) {
      drawSlice(deg, color[i]);
      drawPoin(deg, '#fff');
      drawText(deg + sliceDeg / 2, label[i]);
      deg += sliceDeg;
     }
        if(deg == 0) {
            degreeMultiplier = 0;
            deg=-90;
        }
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
but, how to stop it?

Comment: Assign it to a variable like var abc = setInterval() and clear the setInterval using window.clearInterval(abc);